# German movies or series with 'word-by-word' German subtitles?

Tags: learning, resource, online-resource

This is not a question about German language per se, but about learning it. So down-voters please save it.

Most German movies and series either don't have subtitles or, for example on Mediathek, have subtitles that are not exact or 1:1. The reason is that they make such subtitles for those viewer who have hearing problem or alike, so they make the subtitle more concise, or omit some parts that are not crucial for understanding the story. I have also noticed that sometimes they even replace words with their synonyms, which I don't understand why.

Anyway, I figure there should be here or there some German movies or series that have exact subtitles. For example, on the Internet I found exact German subtitle for the movie 'Untergang'. Now I am looking for more such movies. I appreciate if you write down the name of the movie/series and the address that the subtitles can be found. I believe that would be a great help for those who are learning German.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: Try setting your netflix locale to Germany. I think nearly everything has German subtitles. As for the downvotes ( obligatory I didn't): As you said, this is not about the German language but about language learning, so it's off-topic here.

Comment: I do not think that official subtitles are ever exact.

Comment: @infinitezero So questions about learning German language are off-topic here?

Comment: Was sollen die Apostrophe um "exact" ausdrücken?

Comment: @userunknown   I would suppose Sasan means "word by word" translations. Which of course might turn out the proper opposite of "exact" if you look rather at meaning and pragmatics.

Comment: I don't think that's a question for German SE, maybe rather [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). But as a suggestion: Go to your local store (or online) and buy a (german) DVD of your favourite (english) TV show or movie. The dubbing is good (please no discussion about this) and the subtitles follow them word by word 95% of the time.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're looking for German movies with German subtitles - like you usually get on any DVD bought in Germany. Because the hearing impaired then can watch the movie. You realized that these subtitles differ from what you hear. I assume - I don't know - that is because the subtitles were done by screenplay while the actors ... act and speak situational. => you're looking for German voiced movies with subtitles based on the recorded speaking. There are some fan projects because the publisher lacks provision. Usually they add translations not subtitles for existing dubbing...